# Add bcc to contact from on wordpress

Tags: plugins, php

I found a script for making your own contact form in your wordpress site (without plugin)
Now, I want to add more clients email accounts as a BCC or CC.
how can I do that?

This is me code which define the email address:

```
if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = get_option('tz_email');
        if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
            $emailTo = 'ponim@orot.ac.il';
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: How can we add this bcc email in php code for contact form 7 plugin, i m talking about php code not in plugin interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code uses [`wp_mail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) function to send emails, then you can specify multiple recipients using an array or a comma-separated string.

So your `$emailTo` will be..

```
$emailTo = array(
    'ponim@orot.ac.il',
    'email1@example.com',
    'email2@example.com',
);
```

If your code does not use `wp_mail` function then you can define multiple instance of PHP mail function.

To BCC and CC with `wp_mail`, you must use the `$headers` argument. If it's not already defined in your `wp_mail` then here is a simple example.

```
$headers[] = 'From: Me Myself <me@example.net>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: John Q Codex <jqc@wordpress.org>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: iluvwp@wordpress.org';
```

Although adding email addresses with array (first code) will work just fine, and unless you have a good reason to use BCC/CC headers, you should use it.